# Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. abcd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, runtime-error

I have an error when try get function ExpenseItem() from ExpenseItem.js to  App.js
This is my code

file ExpenseItem.js

```
function ExpenseItem() {
    return <h2>Expense item!</h2>;
}
export default ExpenseItem();
```

and this is app.js

```
import ExpenseItem from "./components/ExpenseItem.js";
function App() {
  return (
    <div> 
      <h2>hello world! </h2>
      <ExpenseItem></ExpenseItem>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

I expected have 2 row: "hello world!" and "Expense item" but nothing appear on display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are calling the function in the export.

Change the `ExpenseItem`-file to this:

```js
function ExpenseItem() {
    return <h2>Expense item!</h2>;
}
export default ExpenseItem; // Don't call the function here
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I realized this problem on docs and fixed them.